# Call to a member function create() on null - laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a post using the current user in Auth.
But i have my error.

Thank you!

Controller

```
public function publish(Post $post){
    $this->validate(request(), [
                'title' => 'required',
                'body'  => 'required'
            ]);


            auth()->user()->publish(
                new Post(request(['title','body']))
            );
        }
```

User model:

```
public function posts()
    {
        $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }


public function publish(Post $post)
{
    $this->posts()->save($post);
}
```

Error
Call to a member function save() on null

Comment: Did you set up the `posts` relationship in the User model?

Comment: Yes Sir here.
 
public function posts()
    {
        $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

Comment: `posts` should return something, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel relationships should `return` the relationship, like this:

```
public function posts()
{
   return  $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't notice. :)